# Jenkins Release Builds With Tag Regex

Tags: regex, git, github, jenkins, release

I would like to build releases with Jenkins once I create a release on GitHub. I use the Git and GitHub plugin.

For versioning, I use the SemVer format. e.g.: `0.0.1-alpha1`

This is my tag regex:

```
refs/tags/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)(?:-([0-9A-Za-z-]+(?:\.[0-9A-Za-z-]+)*))?(?:\+[0-9A-Za-z-]+)?
```

I have set it up like this:

[image: Jenkins Git Plugin]

But it is not triggered on a release. Any idea how to make this work?

(The GitHub hook definitely works)

Comment: Did you make this work ?

Comment: I have not been able to make tags work with a regex.  It's almost as if the regex option forgets to include tags in its matching strategy.

Answer (score 5):

The first part of your regex looks like it might be malformed (for what you want). See an example [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/wU4zU7/1).

If you used something like this, would it satisfy your needs?

```
refs\/tags\/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+[-.]?[\w]*)
```

See [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/aF8eE3/1) for some sample matches